# Planning on switching to Ubuntu!

Tags: installation, drivers, ati, windows-8, amd-processor

I'm planning on taking my HP Envy M6 AMD A10 CPU, with a AMD Radeon HD 7660G discrete-class GPU, and I was wondering if there's any packages I should install to make it run effectively when I first switch. (Drivers, etc.) I hate windows 8; I just want Ubuntu to work well and to still be able to play games on my laptop.
   When I switched my brother's computer, I had a lot of additional packages and things to run before it was operational and I'd prefer to not spend an entire day getting it up and running... Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

look in Software Sources in the last tab yuo can select the driver in there to use, if you add the [xswat ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) you can get the latest stable driver

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maximum performance, use the latest release Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail, but you must upgrade it because it's short release (9 month support).

But I preferably use Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (It's supported until April 2017). Choose Ubuntu 64-bit version if your RAM equal or above 4 GB, use 32 bit version if your RAM below 4 GB. If you use 32 bit, install PAE kernel (32-bit high performance, but still below 64-bit version) after install Ubuntu, follow this guide if you want **install PAE kernel**:

1. Open terminal, press Ctrl + Alt + T

   `$ sudo apt-get install linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae`

   `$ sudo reboot`
2. Enter PAE when on the grub.
3. Remove Non-PAE kernel to prevent unnecessary update

   `$ sudo apt-get remove linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic`

Then,  follow this guide to **install AMD Catalyst**

```
$ sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh   (if file is existing)

$ sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*

$ sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf

$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 xserver-xorg-core

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

$ sudo reboot
```

Command above are not necessary if you never installing AMD Catalyst driver before. Feel free to jump into below guide:

1. Download AMD Catalyst driver from the AMD website http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx . Named amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
2. Create folder with name Catalyst under home directory, /home/your login name/Catalyst
3. Unzip downloaded driver into Catalyst folder. Named amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run
4. Right click the driver file and choose properties. Choose permission tab and tick Execute box, then close.
5. In the terminal

   `$ cd /home/your login name/Catalyst`

   `$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases fakeroot libqtgui4`

   `$ sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1` (for 64-bit version add this command)

   `$ sudo sh ./amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise`

   `$ sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb`

   `$ sudo amdconfig --initial -f`

   `$ sudo reboot`
6. Check the driver installation

   `$ sudo fglrxinfo`

   It should appear like this

   ```
   display: :0  screen: 0

   OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.

   OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4200 Series 

   OpenGL version string: 3.3.11653 Compatibility Profile Context
   ```
7. You have the state of the art ubuntu on your computer!